# Optimize extraction of 64 bit value from AVX2 register

Tags: c, sse, avx, avx2

I try to extract 64 bit from an __m256i register. 
Example of my current extraction function:

```
             byte     31                    16 15                    0
byte_result_vec        000D  000C  000B  000A   000H  000G  000F  000E

_mm256_packs_epi32 ->  0D0C  0B0A  0D0C  0B0A   0H0G  0F0E  0H0G  0F0E

_mm256_packus_epi16 -> DCBA  DCBA  DCBA  DCBA   HGFE  HGFE  HGFE  HGFE
                                         ^^^^                     ^^^^
_mm256_castsi256_si128   -> HGFE  HGFE  HGFE  HGFE

_mm256_extracti128_si256 -> DCBA  DCBA  DCBA  DCBA

_mm_cvtsi128_si32(byte_result_vec1) ->  ABCD

_mm_cvtsi128_si32(byte_result_vec2) ->  EFGH
```

The following code is shifting 4x8 bites to the register position 0-3 and is than extracting 32 bit.

```
        byte_result_vec = _mm256_packs_epi32(byte_result_vec, byte_result_vec);
        byte_result_vec = _mm256_packus_epi16(byte_result_vec, byte_result_vec);
        __m128i byte_result_vec1 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(byte_result_vec);
        __m128i byte_result_vec2 = _mm256_extracti128_si256(byte_result_vec,1);
        const int res1 = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(byte_result_vec1);
        const int res2 = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(byte_result_vec2);
        result_array[j]       = res1;
        result_array[j+1]     = res2;
```

The code is working correct but it is slow. 
It looks like that copying of res1 and res2 to the result_array takes the most time. 
Is there a way to optimize it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably this variant will be faster

```
/* byte_result_vec        000H  000G  000F  000E   000D  000C  000B  000A */
const __m256i shuffle_mask = _mm256_setr_epi8(0,  4,  8, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 4, 8, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
/* abcdefgh               0000  0000  HGFE  0000   0000  0000  0000  DCBA */
const __m256i abcdefgh = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(byte_result_vec, shuffle_mask);
/* abcd                                            0000  0000  0000  DCBA */
const __m128i abcd = _mm256_castsi256_si128(abcdefgh);
/* efgh                                            0000  0000  HGFE  0000 */
const __m128i efgh = _mm256_extracti128_si256(abcdefgh, 1);
_mm_storel_epi64((__m128i*)&result_array[j], _mm_or_si128(abcd, efgh));
```

Comment: I just found that there is an additional optimization opportunity: one can replace `_mm256_castsi256_si128` + `_mm256_extracti128_si256` + `_mm_or_si128` with a single `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32` to same another cycle of latency.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between `_mm256_castsi256_si128` and `_mm256_castsf256_si128`. The first requires AVX2 and the second only AVX. Why should one ever use `_mm256_castsi256_si128`?

Comment: `_mm256_castsi256_si128` is a no-op and requires only `AVX`. Similarly, other casts are no-ops, they differ only in argument/result types.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question. I meant what's the difference between `_mm256_extractf128_si256` and `_mm256_extracti128_si256`. I know those casts are no-ops just to make the compiler happy. I mean this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684454/vextractf128-versus-vextracti128?noredirect=1#comment40141720_25684454

Comment: Intel CPUs traditionally have separate register files and data paths for integer and floating-point registers. Thus, `VEXTRACTI128` might be implemented in the integer part of SIMD core and connected to integer SIMD register file, and `VEXTRACTF128` - in the floating-point part and connected to FP SIMD register file. So, if you use `VEXTRACTI128` with data that resulted from floating-point operation (and thus the register resides in FP file), there may be a few-cycle latency to move the data between the parts of SIMD core.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I was thinking. It causes a domain change.